# What are my options for renting small amounts of land for outdoor gardening in an urban setting?

Tags: urban-gardening

I live in a small apartment with small balconies. If I'm going to grow some veggies, I need more space!

I tried my local community garden, but it has a 3 year waiting list..

Are there any other options out there for renting land on a small scale (think 5 square meters)? Any craigslist remix for backyard rentals?

I live in Montreal but I'm equally interested in solutions that exist elsewhere!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To find land you're going to have to work two routes at the same time.

First, join one or all of the following sites...

[SharingBackYards.com](http://www.sharingbackyards.com/)

[WePatch.org](http://www.wepatch.org)

[Please edit to include any other good sites you find]

Once you're signed up, start working locally using tools like [meetup.com](http://www.meetup.com) and [craigslist.org](http://www.craigslist.org) to get people your information.

Also I'd like to stress that vegetables can be grown in a small apartment and on a small balcony.

[Container Gardening](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/containers)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! Not available in my city, but very interesting none the less.

Answer (score 4):

There was an [article on garden sharing](http://www.guardian.co.uk/money/2011/sep/02/garden-sharing-growing-vegetables) in the paper recently. I don't have any experience of it but basically the piece describes how you are matched up with folk who are either too busy or too elderly to look after their own garden. So you work their plot and you split the harvest with them.

Maybe there's a scheme like that in your area or you could start one yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried posting "garden space wanted" on craigslist yet? Beyond that, I might suggest looking for local gardening clubs and asking the membership if anyone has space they'd like to share.

A different approach would be to look for a local CSA. Not the same as growing your own veg, but some CSAs need volunteers -- and allow your volunteer time to offset your membership price. Alternatively, the folks that you meet there may be able to steer you toward someone who would rent you some space.